# how can i force gcc to link a static library?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-linking

I write a static library: libA.a. I have another application called B.o. B.o doesn't used any functions in libA.a. I want to combine libA.o into B.o, then I could call some stuff in libA.a by other methods, when B.o is running.

I write makefile like this: `gcc B.c -o B.o -lA -u symbol_A`. Here -u is from GCC manual:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

It suggests use -u to force linking unused library, and symbol_A is some symbol in libA.a

But it doesn't work. After linking, I can not find any LibA.a's stuff in B.o.

May anyone give me some hint?

p.s I am using GCC 3.4.4, eclipse+CDT under windows, and B.o will be deployed under linux.

Comment: Are you trying to create an object file or an executable?  If an executable they normally don't have .o suffix.  By the looks of things you're trying to undefine the function `symbol_A.Here` so that gcc plugs the definition from the library.  Any reason why you'd want to do this?

Comment: If nothing from B uses anything from libA, then nothing from libA will be added.

Comment: p.s I am using GCC 3.4.4, eclipse+CDT under windows, and B.o will be deployed under linux.

Comment: But here, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html, GCC's manual said it could force linking.....

Comment: @user1134355 Read the description carefully.  This option tells GCC that symbol is undefined and forces the link even though the symbol may be defined in your object file.

Comment: to Karlson, B.o running under a special circumstance. Any non-static functions could be directly called via telnet.

Comment: @user1134355 You might want to explain this one.

Comment: @Karlson, it writes:
Pretend the symbol symbol is undefined, to force linking of library modules to define it. You can use -u multiple times with different symbols to force loading of additional library modules. 
form literal, if i undefine some symbol's from libA.a, GCC will be forced to find it from libA.a, so that libA.a will be linked into B.o. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Karlson, it is some shell-tools, write by someone else. It could invoke any non-static functions, when i type it through telnet. I want use some functions from libA.a to monitor B.o's running state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation of the `-u` flag from GCC means the following:

> If you have a symbol aka variable or function that is defined in your source tell 
>   GCC to pretend that it is undefined so it takes the definition of such variable or
>   function from the library you are linking.

So if your `B.c` has nothing that may be defined in `libA.a` the `-u` flag won't help you since the `symbol_A` is not needed by `B.c` and by the same token `B.o`, so will be simply ignored.